# Regex inside angle brackets, quotes or spaces

Tags: regex

I'm having a particular regex which finds some value in text data, for example any 10 letters, like `[a-zA-Z]{10}`. The problem is that this value should be only inside angle brackets, quotes or spaces and the value should be extracted as a result. For example in this case:

`<a>abcdefghij</a>` - Matched

`"abcdefghij"`  - Matched

`abc abcdefghij abc`  - Matched

`abcabcdefghijabc`  -  Not matched

And the result of applying the regex on each matched of them should be the value inside, in this case `abcdefghij`. Any ideas how to write it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try this:

Regex:

```
(?<=\W)[a-zA-Z]{10}(?=\W)
```

Explanation: Angle brackets, Quotes, Double-Quotes, space are all non-word characters. So we can use Positive lookbehind and positive lookahead searching for such non-word characters around the 10 Alphabets.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mkbOfg/5

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @YuriyYunikov You're welcome. If you think this is the regex you were looking for, please accept/select it as the answer.

Comment: sure. Wasn't able to accept it until some period of time :)